# How to formate Seagate 2 TB External Hard disk for Mac OS X

Tags: hard-drive, mac

I Have a Seagate 2 T.B External H.D.D.How do I format it so that I can use it for cross plateform O.S(Windows;Linux;OS X.) Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, format it with *exFAT* file system under Windows. The *exFAT* filesystem is supported also in OS X. To use it under Ubuntu, make sure you have packages *exfat-utils* and *exfat-fuse* installed.